# Cannot read property 'setPosition' HTML5

Tags: html, google-maps

My objective right now is to basically add a marker wherever the user is in the google maps. The API works, a KML file I added with polygons work and i'm sure it doesn't mess with any of the code so far.

However, I have" Cannot read property 'setPosition' of undefined" error at line 99 of the code. it will probably have an easy solution but I cannot see it myself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAjp8cvAcEYCwzuCyTQORL3Z1iQPdQMg_8&callback=initMap" async defer>
        </script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <title>Protoype: Just Don't</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body, #map {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            /* Style the buttons so that they are consistently coloured and sized */
            .button {
                background-color: #008CBA; /* Blue */
                border: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 15px 32px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 16px;
            }

            /* Style the search box */
            .search input[type=text] {
                float: right;
                padding: 6px;
                border: none;
                margin-top: 8px;
                margin-right: 16px;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

            /* When the screen is less than 640px wide, stack the search field vertically instead of horizontally */
            @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
                .search a, .search input[type=text] {
                    float: none;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: left;
                    width: 100%;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 14px;
                }
                .search input[type=text] {
                    border: 1px solid #ccc;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<h3>Just don't app test</h3>

<div class="search">
    <input type=text placeholder="Search..">
</div>

<a href="#" button class="button" onclick="alert('Takes user to settings page')">Settings</a>
<a href="#" button class="button" onclick="alert('Allows user to create/edit account')">Account</a>
<a href="#" button class="button" onclick="alert('Allows user to add a review to an area')">Add Review</a>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    var map, infoWindow;
    function initMap() {
        InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        var Paisley = {lat: 55.845890, lng: -4.423741};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 17,
            center: Paisley
        });
       var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/just-don-t.appspot.com/o/Project%20examples.kml?alt=media&token=65140cfc-de3a-4658-8b2b-0354f4909d38',
            suppressInfoWindows: true,
            map: map
        });

        kmlLayer.addListener('click', function(kmlEvent) {
            var text = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
            showInContentWindow(text);
        });

        function showInContentWindow(text) {
            var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
            sidediv.innerHTML = text;
        }

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                ;
                var  pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                infoWindow.setPosition (pos);
                infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
                infoWindow.open(map);
                map.setCenter(pos);
            }, function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Any tips on how to solve it or if you find another problem in my code will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update: apparently the problem is with the infowindow, i'm trying to apply it to a non-existent marker. Will work on it today and update if found solution.

Comment: which is line 99?

Comment: infoWindow.setPosition (pos);

Comment: It looks to be a typo - `InfoWindow` and `infoWindow` would be different variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I believe was the mismatch in variable names. Initially you declared `InfoWindow` when creating the reference but throughout thereafter refer to `infoWindow`. Additionally the functions `showInContentWindow` and `handleLocationError` needn't be declared within the `initMap` function.

The following works OK - but the `geoLocation` puts the `Location found` nowhere near Paisley for me ... the css here was just basic for testing.

Anyone would think Paisley was an unsafe place after dark judging by some of the descriptions that appear when clicking on the KML Layer - never saw much of Paisley when we used to go to 'Club69' back in the day...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Maps: KML Layer</title>
        <script id='gm' async defer src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAjp8cvAcEYCwzuCyTQORL3Z1iQPdQMg_8&callback=initMap&region=en-GB&language=en"></script>
        <script>

            var infowindow, map, Paisley, kmlLayer;
            var text, pos

            function initMap(){
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                Paisley = { lat: 55.845890, lng: -4.423741 };

                map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 17,
                    center: Paisley
                });

                kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
                    url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/just-don-t.appspot.com/o/Project%20examples.kml?alt=media&token=65140cfc-de3a-4658-8b2b-0354f4909d38',
                    suppressInfoWindows: true,
                    map: map
                });

                kmlLayer.addListener( 'click', function( event ) {
                    text = event.featureData.description;
                    showInContentWindow( text );
                });


                if( navigator.geolocation ) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( function( position ) {
                        pos = {
                            lat: position.coords.latitude,
                            lng: position.coords.longitude
                        };
                        infowindow.setPosition( pos );
                        infowindow.setContent( 'Location found.' );
                        infowindow.open( map );
                        map.setCenter( pos );

                        console.info( 'Location found: %s, %s', pos.lat, pos.lng );
                    }, function() {
                        handleLocationError( true, infowindow, map.getCenter() );
                    });
                } else {
                    handleLocationError( false, infowindow, map.getCenter() );
                }

            }

            function showInContentWindow( text ) {
                document.getElementById('content-window').innerHTML = text;
            }
            function handleLocationError( browserHasGeolocation, infowindow, pos ) {
                infowindow.setPosition( pos );
                infowindow.setContent( browserHasGeolocation ? 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' : 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
                infowindow.open( map );
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            body{ background:white; }
            #container{
                width: 90%;
                min-height: 90vh;
                height:auto;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                margin: auto;
                float:none;
                margin:1rem auto;
                background:whitesmoke;
                padding:1rem;
                border:1px solid gray;
                display:block;
            }
            #map {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                clear:none;
                display:block;
                z-index:1!important;
                background:white;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='map'></div>
            <div id='content-window'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I ended up creating the whole code back from the start and got it to work flawlessly. However I did learn from your code to watch myself with my typos and such, thanks a lot.

Also, Paisley ain't that bad, its just for the sake of testing for my university I barely know the place but chose random locations for the information!